# API for receiving payments through VISA/Mastercard Credit/Debit cards & paypal

Tags: java, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment, credit-card

I need to accept payments from the premium account holders on my website through VISA/Mastercard Credit/Debit Cards & paypal. Is there any well known widely used API that can make my life easier by abstracting all these payment procedures?

Comment: Try Visa Checkout API that is available on Visa Developer - https://developer.visa.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IP*Works! from [nSoftware](http://www.nsoftware.com) has a good toolset:  [ICharge Payment Integrator](http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/icharge.aspx)

However, unless you are fully prepared for the nightmare that is [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/), just use [Authorize.Net](http://www.authorize.net/) or [PayPal's standard methods](https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/wp_standard&nav=0.3.3).  What they charge you in fees you will be more than happy to pay compared to what happens if you lose credit card numbers to hacking.